# Не работает функция напоминалки на Ruby

Tags: telegram-bot, ruby

В телеграмм боте я создаю функцию напоминалки, чтобы ты мог в него ввести когда тебе напомнить и о чем напомнить. Написал скрипт, но в консоли выдало ошибку:

```
Pietya.rb
Pietya.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined local variable or method `user_data' for main:Object (NameError)

                case user_data['state']
                     ^^^^^^^^^
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/telegram-bot-ruby-1.0.0/lib/telegram/bot/client.rb:36:in `block in fetch_updates'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/telegram-bot-ruby-1.0.0/lib/telegram/bot/client.rb:35:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/telegram-bot-ruby-1.0.0/lib/telegram/bot/client.rb:35:in `fetch_updates'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/telegram-bot-ruby-1.0.0/lib/telegram/bot/client.rb:27:in `listen'
        from Pietya.rb:26:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/telegram-bot-ruby-1.0.0/lib/telegram/bot/client.rb:20:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/telegram-bot-ruby-1.0.0/lib/telegram/bot/client.rb:10:in `run'
        from Pietya.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

Вот код бота:

```
require "telegram/bot"

token = ""

def set_reminder_time(bot, message, user_data)
    bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: 'Введите время напоминания в формате "чч:мм":')
    user_data['state'] = 'SET_REMINDER_TIME'
end

def set_reminder_text(bot, message, user_data)
    user_data['reminder_time'] = message.text
    bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: 'Введите текст напоминания:')
    user_data['state'] = 'SET_REMINDER_TEXT'
end

def set_reminder(bot, message, user_data)
    reminder_text = message.text
    reminder_time = user_data['reminder_time']

    bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Напоминание установлено на #{reminder_time} с текстом: #{reminder_text}")

end

Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
    bot.listen do |message|
        case message.text
        when "Ты молодец", "Ты крутой", "Ты лучший" 
            bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Спасибо бро :3")
        end

        case message.text
        when "/start" 
            bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Здарова, #{message.from.first_name}. Я Петя, твой лучший друг. Я буду помогать тебе с твоими делами. Придумаю развлекуху, помогу вспомнить о том, о чем ты забыл и т.д.")
        end

        case message.text
        when "Чем заняться", "Что мне делать", "Что делать если мне скучно" 
            bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Братан, в мире есть очень много развлекух, сходи в кино, Захвати других кунтов и сходи с ними на речку, в парк, или просто куда глаза глядят. Сыграй в фудбик, баскет. Помог?")
        when "Нет", "Не особо", "Не помог"
            bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Попробуй поигать в компуктер, если надоело порисуй, почитай, глянь новое аниме")
        when "Да", "Конечно", "Ещё как", "Спасибо", "Спс"
            bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Ну и хорошо")
        end

        case message.text
        when "Что делать если грустно", "Мне грустно", "Я чувствую себя не очень хорошо" 
            bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Братан, успокойся, бывают разные сетуации, дерьмо пройдет и житуха наладится.")
        end

        case message.text
        when "Расскажи анекдот", "Расскажи шутку", "Поведай смешную историю" 
            bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Появился, значит, в Зоне Чёрный сталкер. К лагерю ночью повадился ходить и там сует руку в палатку и говорит: «Водички попить!» А если не дашь хлебнуть из фляжки или наружу полезешь — пришибет! А раз мужик один решил пошутить: вылез тихо из палатки, надел кожаную перчатку и полез к соседям в палатку. Полез, значит, и попрошайничает жалостно: «Водички, водички попить…» А тут из палатки навстречу высовывается рука и за горло его — цап! И сиплый голосок отзывается тихонько: «А тебе моя водичка зачем нужна?!»")
        end

        case message.text
        when "/set_reminder"
            bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Брат, я могу тебе напомнить о чём угодно, просто введи '/event <hour><minute> <text>'")
        end

        case message.text
        when '/set_reminder'
            set_reminder_time(bot, message, user_data)
        else
            case user_data['state']
            when 'SET_REMINDER_TIME'
                set_reminder_text(bot, message, user_data)
            when 'SET_REMINDER_TEXT'
                set_reminder(bot, message, user_data)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Переменная user_data у вас действительно нигде не определяется, что вас удивляет?